# Some subject rows in email show up as gibberish in OSX Mail app

Tags: macos, apple-mail

A client is reporting strange subject rows in Mail for OSX:

[image: Weird subject row]

I can't seem to find the cause or any pattern. I know however that it's only client side, because when checking in Outlook, or a webmail-client, the subject row is shown correct.

It's an automated mail sent from a system, so I assume it's possible it could be an encoding error, but I've never seen an encoding error show up like this, and it doesn't show on every email, just a few of them.

Sadly I can't show more details about the email, but I figured I'd try asking here anyway.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `base64` encoded email header that is not being decoded.

```
$ echo "UHJvZHVrdHJlZG92aXNuaW5nIGkgcHJvamVrdCBCcnVrc2fDpXJkZW=" | base64 -D
Produktredovisning i project Bruksgård
```

I might have mistyped some characters.

Comment: *Bruksgård* seems to be a name, and in total it doesn't look confidential without other information, so I decided to just post it.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. I've been trying to find out why this string isn't decoded but several others are. I posted a question on StackOverflow about it in case there's something I can do about the actual sending of the mail, which is automated from a C# client. Thanks for the help.